# Timer even and Message box

Tags: c#

I have listbox and I want to check with timer event if my variable which I read from txt file is equal to one of in the listbox. If it is equal I pop message box with YES and NO. If I press Yes it changes some text in another configuration file. But I have problem with seems like timer event or reading from listbox. I am able to read and compare but if I press NO message box goes away, but after timer event trigger for second time and I press NO it pops two messages boxes, after third timer event 4 messages boxes and etc.

```
        private void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool Found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string item = listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
            if (item == Globals.vivaboard)
            {
                Found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (Found)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Press YES to enable", "iTAC Disabled" + " " + Globals.vivaboard, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                auto_change();
                listBox2.Items.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                Form2_Load();
            }
            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                Form2_Load();
                Found = false;
                //WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
        }
        timer2.Stop();
        OTPM_Viva();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think (if I correctly understood your use case)  thatit would be better to use a FileSystemWatcher : instead of using timers, you will observe the file's changes. Your callback method, inside which you will read your variable, will be called only when the file is modified.
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0

Comment: Not really, item in Listbox is most important, and i can see it visually but due to human error I have to check if its same as its loaded in other test program. If it is same I have to pop message for operator so he dont produce scrap. But if it is not the same it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

So problem was with me calling Timer event twice. `OTPM_Viva();`
Once here and second time inside the event itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).